# Graph a custom variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a simple "Java Request" sampler (ie: AbstractJavaSamplerClient).  How do I produce custom variables from this sampler and graph these? (Preferably with out-of-the-box graphing listeners).  Currently I can only easily graph sample times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your var in JMeter:

```
JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().put("YOUR_VAR", value)
```

And add in user.properties:

```
sample_variables=YOUR_VAR
```

Your var will be output in CSV ou XML.

You can then use it.

Comment: How do you put this in Jmeter?