# Changing user defined variables in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a custom JMeter sampler, which derives from `AbstractJavaSamplerClient`. In this sampler, I want to change a user defined variable in the JMeter GUI after the sampler finishes. I can access user defined variables using

```
JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables()
```

but changing values in these variables using the `put` method does not reflect in the GUI. Is this even possible?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809877/graph-a-custom-variable-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible as when you do this, it is on running copy of components.